# Facing issue after moving weblogic specific configuration (only) from annotations to weblogic-ejb-jar.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, weblogic

I have few MDBs and SessionBeans that use weblogic specific configuration (initial-beans-in-free pool, max-beans-in-free-pool, etc)
I was using annotation for this before in all the ejbs.
No I'm using javax annotations for generic configuration and moving all the weblogic specific configuration to weblogic-ejb-jar.xml (this will have precedence over the annotation configuration).
I have different ejbs in different projects (or modules).
The issue is that I'm facing some issue after this change only in one of the module.
I'm getting class not found exception for a class which is in the same module but is not connected to the ejbs changed in this module.
If I revoke the change done in ejb of this module everything works fine.
Strange thing is that I have done similar changes in other ejbs which are in other different modules and they are working fine.
What can be the reason behind this class not found exception? The class file is present in the jar.

WL version is 10.3.4.
All the modules are in the same ear. The changes for rest of the modules are working fine. Only in one module I get class not found exception which is not at all related to ejbs I changed.
I have adding following to weblogic-ejb-jar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.2/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd">
 <wls:description></wls:description>
   <wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean>
      <wls:ejb-name>RefreshConsumer</wls:ejb-name>
      <wls:message-driven-descriptor>
         <wls:pool>
            <wls:max-beans-in-free-pool>5</wls:max-beans-in-free-pool>
            <wls:initial-beans-in-free-pool>1</wls:initial-beans-in-free-pool>
         </wls:pool>
         <wls:destination-jndi-name>trivnet.wisp.RefreshTopic</wls:destination-jndi-name>
         <wls:connection-factory-jndi-name>trivnet.wisp.JMSTopicFactory</wls:connection-factory-jndi-name>
      </wls:message-driven-descriptor>
   </wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean>
</wls:weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

Rest of the configuration for this MDB in its class provided as annotation.

Comment: what version of weblogic? are they are modules in the same EAR? can you post the stacktrace as well?

Comment: added the details in the question. 
One important thing, :I'm getting class not found exception while deploying the application.